# SharedPreferences fails to read file (android 2.x)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I've got a very strange error: PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences fails to read from the settings file.

I do like this:

1. Set breakpoint at the first time `SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());` is called at the beginning of the first activity and step one line below. I check that `pref.mFile` is the correct file, but `pref.mMap` is empty!!
2. I open Es File Explorer, finds the preference file and opens it. All preferences are there, just that PreferenceManager fails to read them somehow, so when going to settings screen, nothing is saved.

I've tried to clear all data for the app, but same problem next time I change settings an re-launch the app.

I get this error on Android 2.x phones. I build against android 4.2.2, using Eclipse, latest sdk tools, target sdk version 17.

Any ideas why or how it can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem after some hours of debugging: some strings saved to the settings file contained invalid characters so if failed when parsing the xml file when reading it next time.